# ESP32 3.3V Voltage Regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, ldo, esp32

I'm designing a circuit which will include an ESP32 and 5V DC power provided by a AC/DC SMPS.
The 5V is needed for other components in the circuit and I would like to power the ESP32 through its 3v3 in pin from this source.

https://techexplorations.com/guides/esp32/begin/power/

https://uk.farnell.com/multicomp-pro/mp-ld10-23b05r2/power-supply-ac-dc-5v-2a/dp/3583991

Please can you suggest a suitable way to regulate the 5V down to 3.3V?
LDO as on ESP32 dev kits some other component?

Comment: Is there any reason you think a 3.3V LDO, like the AMS1117-3.3 used on some of the dev kits, would not be suitable?

Comment: @TypeIA I'd wondered if there was a more efficient/ better suited component for the job.

Comment: "Better suited" to what - you didn't specify any requirements or what the application is. If very high power efficiency is a (justified) design goal, then an LDO may not be the best option since unlike a switching supply, it dissipates the excess ~1.7V as heat. It sounds like you probably know this already though.

Comment: The device this circuit is for will be mains powered 247, so better suited for efficiency.

Comment: Ballpark math: the ESP32 runs around 100-200 mA "awake" depending on radio mode. Doing the math, at 200 mA, the LDO will waste around 1/3 watt (on top of the 2/3 watt useful power). That's about 3 kW-hr over a year. You can reduce this _hugely_ if you are able to take advantage of the ESP32's sleep/power saving modes. Calculate the cost of this electricity in your country and compare against the design cost of a more efficient (= more complex) power solution.

Comment: What kind of ESP32 are you using, a dev board, a module like ESP32-WROOM-32 or the naked chip?

Comment: @Codo a dev kit v1 Dev board currently, but this will be replaced by a bare chip when I move to PCB